# embedding a visualforce page in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, visualforce-component

I used an iframe to embed my visualforce page in a lightning component, but the page is showing me the error: Refused to display, in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. is this because my VF page is calling web services? if so, what could be done?

Comment: check if your development mode is turned on, that may be the issue.

Comment: similar to your's:- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/x-frame-option-set-to-deny-in-i-frame-inside-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String"
            default="yourdomain-dev-ed--c.na35.visual.force.com"/>

    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/myvfpage'}"/>

</aura:component>
```

I have tried embedding a visualforce inside a lightning component and also tried sending data from Lightning to Visualforce. In case you need it, here's a reference: [Communicating between Lightning Components and Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)